# Subset a List by Partial String Match from a Tibble Dataframe

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have following file list as `listOfCELfiles`

```
listOfCELfiles <- c(
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514737.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514738.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514739.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514740.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514741.CEL.gz", 
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514742.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514743.CEL.gz", 
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514744.CEL.gz", 
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514745.CEL.gz"
)
```

And a dataframe as `timepoint_table`

```
timepoint_table <- tibble(SampleID = c("GSM514737","GSM514738","GSM514739","GSM514740","GSM514741","GSM514742","GSM514743","GSM514744","GSM514745"),
SampleName = c("Blood_alcohol_T1_S13", "Blood_alcohol_T2_S13","Blood_OJalcohol_T3_S13","Blood_alcohol_T4_S13","Blood_OJalcohol_T5_S13","Blood_alcohol_T1_S15","Blood_alcohol_T2_S15","Blood_OJalcohol_T3_S15","Blood_OJalcohol_T4_S15"))
```

So `timepoint_table` looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  SampleID  SampleName            
  <chr>     <chr>                 
1 GSM514737 Blood_alcohol_T1_S13  
2 GSM514738 Blood_alcohol_T2_S13  
3 GSM514739 Blood_OJalcohol_T3_S13
4 GSM514740 Blood_alcohol_T4_S13  
5 GSM514741 Blood_OJalcohol_T5_S13
6 GSM514742 Blood_alcohol_T1_S15  
7 GSM514743 Blood_alcohol_T2_S15  
8 GSM514744 Blood_OJalcohol_T3_S15
9 GSM514745 Blood_OJalcohol_T4_S15
```

The `SampleID` is part of the file-names in `listOfCELfiles` Now I want to remove any sample other than `Blood_alcohol` from `listOfCELfiles` by matching from the `timepoint_table`'s `SampleName`. The following code selects the matching `SampleID`s from `timepoint_table`

```
timepoint_table %>%
  filter(str_detect(SampleName, "^Blood_alcohol")) %>%
  select(SampleID)
```

But I cannot filter `listOfCELfiles` with this matched `SampleID`s (using `grepl` or `str_detect`).

My expected output will be a list which contains:

```
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514737.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514738.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514740.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514742.CEL.gz",
"GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514743.CEL.gz",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the ids that match and then filter them using `grep`

```
library(tidyverse)

ids <- timepoint_table %>%  
         filter(str_detect(SampleName, "^Blood_alcohol")) %>%  
         pull(SampleID)

grep(paste0(ids, collapse = "|"), listOfCELfiles, value = TRUE)

#[1] "GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514737.CEL.gz" "GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514738.CEL.gz"
#[3] "GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514740.CEL.gz" "GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514742.CEL.gz"
#[5] "GSE20489/GSE20489_RAW//GSM514743.CEL.gz"
```